# Cannot GET /api/business-partners in approuter application

Tags: s4sdk

​Hi Experts,
I am following https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h13/items/258qEhXx5kdG8b4SXMSJYp tutorial, after deploying the app I am getting 404 for my servlets in approuter application while same servets are giving me 'http 401' in 'address-manager' as expected.
​has anyone done this successfully? if so then please guide me in the right direction.
​I have gone through everything I could think of, but I can't get past this issue.

xs-app.json file content

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "index.html",
  "routes": [
  {
    "source": "^/api/(.*)",
    "target": "/api/$1",
    "destination": "app-destination"
  },
  {
    "source": "^/address-manager/(.*)",
    "target": "/address-manager/$1",
    "destination": "app-destination"
  }],
  "logout" : {
    "logoutEndpoint": "/logout",
    "logoutPage": "/logout.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Armoghan, can you share your xs-app.json file of the approuter and the content of the destinations environment variable of the approuter? A 404 Not Found indicates that something if off there. Are you able to access the static content of the frontend via the approuter?

Comment: 1 - I am able ro run approuter app & login, as shown in the tutorial, but I get 404 for my servlets (which is next step according to the video), even Logout is working fine. hence I'd say that the static content is accessible via approuter.

2 - destination value in approuter's manifest.yml= destinations: '[{"name":"app-destination", "url" :"https://odata-mock-server-tired-<random text>.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/", "forwardAuthToken": true}]'

3:  xs-app.json file content : I have updated it in the post.

Comment: Hi @HenningHeitkötter thanks fro response, I have updated my post with the xs-app.json code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `destinations` environment variable of the approuter on SAP Cloud Platform, Cloud Foundry needs to reference the URL(s) at which you reach the application(s) that you want to access via the route(s) defined in the approuter. (Not to be confused with the `destinations` environment variable that you may be using as a placeholder in athe backend application built with the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK.)

In your case, this should probably be some URL pointing to the address-manager, your target application. In the example value mentioned in your comment, you point to the mock server instead, which is probably not what you want.

Change the `destinations` environment variable to the following and push / restart the application again. (Insert the URL that points to your address manager application deployment.)

```
[{"name":"app-destination", "url" :"address-manager-<random text>.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/", "forwardAuthToken": true}]
```

The fact that you can login and logout despite the misconfigured destination is expected, because those paths are actually served by the approuter itself.

Comment: thanks, I had overlooked the url part in manifet.yml file, it worked fine after I made the suggested change